# For loops with API feeds and Liquid Logic

Tags: for-loop, liquid

I'm trying to use for loops to search for specific objects in a connected API feed and then save the data to local variables. I'm using Braze and liquid logic. I've gotten this to work in another use case but I believe the data was structured in a way that was easier for me to use for loops.
An example object from the API:

```
{
    "data": {
        "jackpotGames": [
            {
                "jackpotDetails": {
                "jackpotId": "01234",
                "operatorId": "56789",
                "locations": [
                    "US-NJ"
                ],
                "supportedCurrencies": [
                    "USD",
                    "CAD"
                ],
                "isAutoOptIn": false,
                "termsAndConditions": "terms would go here",
                "title": null,
                "details": null
                },
                "potDetails": [
                {
                    "currentPotAmount": 221005.4,
                    "isProgressiveJackpot": true,
                    "level": 1,
                    "potName": "pot1",
                }
            ],
        }
    ]   
    }
}
```

I'm looking to use for loops to find an object where the location is "x" and then save the currentPotAmount to a local variable that I can use.

I've written a couple of different iterations but nothings worked so far. Again, this code has worked with another API but not with this one - not sure if this is due to how the data is nested or my code doesn't work for this use case.

```
{% connected_content 'API URL HERE' :save connectedjackpot :retry %}

{% assign jurisdiction = "US-NJ" %}
{% assign jurisdictionFound = false %}

{% for jackpot in connectedjackpot.data %}
{% for game in jackpot.jackpotGames %}
{% for details in game.jackpotDetails %}
{% for location in details.locations %}
{% if location.locations contains {{jurisdiction}} %}
{% assign jurisdictionFound = true %}
{% assign jackpotId = details.jackpotId %}
{% assign state = location.locations %}
{% break %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I then use this code to check if the above is working:

```
    {% if {{jackpotFound}} == false %}
    False
    {% else %}
    True
    {% endif %}
```

I keep getting False

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where jackpotFound is ever being assigned. Try adding {% assign jackpotFound = true %} to the other assign statements in your if-block.

Comment: Please use the comment function for comments.